# Scroll two ListViews simultaneously in C# 4

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have 2 ListViews in my Form. The 1st one has few strings. After doing some modifications, i'm showing the same in the 2nd one. Now, if i want to compare, i have to scroll both the 1st one and 2nd one. Is there any way to capture the scroll event on 1st one and make the 2nd one scroll same distance ?

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851620/handling-scroll-event-on-listview-in-c look this thred...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't had the chance to do this in recent times, but earlier I used to employ the Sendmessage API

You could make a Sendmessage call, and send a scroll message (look up google to find the exact message) to the second listbox on the scroll event of the first one.