# Get coordinates within listview when scrolled down

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, scroll, coordinate

I would like to get the 'real' Y-value of the point i clicked on when scrolled down a listview.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" MaxHeight="350" MinHeight="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="MyListView" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and here the code:

```
Class MainWindow 
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 100
        MyListView.Items.Add(i)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub MyListView_MouseLeftButtonUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles MyListView.MouseLeftButtonUp
    MsgBox(e.GetPosition(MyListView).Y)
End Sub
End Class
```

My problem now is that no matter how far down I scrolled, the top is always 1 and the bottom is always 309, but when scrolled down i would like to get values higher than 309.
Is there any way to find out the 'real' Y-coordinate I clicked on or maybe find out how far down I scrolled and then being able to calculate the adjusted value?
Wrapping the listview in a scrollviewer control is not an option btw.

Thanks for any answers

Comment: Welcome to Staock Overflow.   Your question is well written, but you can improve things by adding tags that describe the languages relevant to the question

Comment: Hopefully someone will be along who can actually answer the question.   I'm not a vb.net person, but generally I would expect the answer to this question to entail asking the scroller how far it is scrolled.  Maybe that is something to look into...

Comment: This was my first idea, but I got no Idea how to access the built in ScrollViewer of the ListView. I do not want to wrap an extra scrollviewer around the control.
Solutions in vb.net or C# appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851620/handling-scroll-event-on-listview-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks, the link helped. By calling Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Mylistview,0).Child I got the Scrollviewer and apparently Scrollviewer.VerticalOffset gives me the amount of Items Scrolled down and that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Yay.  I summarised our finding in an answer - if you would be kind enough to accept (or critique) that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to determine the real Y value, you need to know the amount that has been scrolled, which the scrollviewer can tell you.

You can obtain the scrollviewer as a child of the listview (`Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Mylistview,0).Child`) , and from there the vertical offset it currently has (`Scrollviewer.VerticalOffset`).
The vertical Offset does not give you the the y-coordinate-offset, instead you get the amount of listview-items scrolled down. You can easily work with that.