# How to detect : scrolling - up or down?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, scroll

System.Windows.Forms.Form has only one scroll event-**Scroll**, but it is necessary to recognize ***scrolling up*** and ***scrolling down***.Could you tell me,how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the passed System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs arguments' OldValue and NewValue properties to detect the scroll direction.

Answer (score 5):

```
private void dgv_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OldValue > e.NewValue)
            {
                // here up
            }
            else
            {
                // here down
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [`ScrollEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.aspx) Class and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176703/listview-onscroll-event/1176794#1176794).