# Change behaviour of listbox scrollbars in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox, scrollbar, .net-cf-3.5

I have a winforms project with a large listbox. My aim is to change some of the functionality of the scrollbars of the list. Firstly, I am trying to navigate through the items in the list using the scrollbar. i.e. moving the scrollbar up and down changes which item is selected. I know programatically you can change the selected index by using

```
listbox1.SelectedIndex=*index*
```

My idea so far is to lock the scroll bar in one of 3 positions (UP/NEUTRAL/DOWN) to increment and decrement *index*. To do this i was thinking of disabling the vertical scrollbar ([Hide vertical scroll bar in ListBox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169900/hide-vertical-scroll-bar-in-listbox-control))
and use a custom one. Problem is i have so far been unable to find and information on how to link the new scrollbar to the list and/or change its behaviour. In fact i don't even know if it's possible to do.
Hoping to clarify: if the scrollbar is moved up, it changes focus to the previous item in the list. If it is moved down, it changes focus to the next item. Basically something similar to the iphone selection wheel.

Any ideas or suggestions on how i can make the scrollbar do this or any other object which could? Thank you.

Comment: Just thinking out loud.  You could display only a fixed number of items in the ListBox so that scrollbars never appear (you'll have to keep the master list separately in the code).  Then place two buttons off to the side for up/down.  If the selected index is at the top or bottom and a "scroll" is needed then update the fixed items displayed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I had a similar idea of using buttons and a keydown handler but i was really hoping for a way of doing this using a slider or scrollbar

Comment: Well...not sure about Compact Framework.  In WinForms you could derive from ListBox and trap WM_VSCROLL messages in WndProc() to know when the ListBox has been scrolled.  Then check to see if the SelectedIndex is visible to the user using TopIndex() and some calculations to get the bottom index.  Change SelectedIndex() afterwards to keep the selection in the currently scrolled area.  Check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8009602/2330053) by LarsTech for some code code to start from.  Again, though, I'm not sure if this approach is valid in Compact Framework.